# Windows Azure Cloud computing application with IIS 5.0 or 6.0

Tags: azure

I am newbie to Windows Azure application. I have downloaded the Microsoft Visual Studio express edition 2010 BETA and want to develop Window Azure application. My PC is having Microsoft Windows XP Service Pack 2 with IIS 5.0.

Will Windows Azure cloud application work on IIS 5.0 or IIS 6.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK azure can run any asp.net application. I don't think you will have issues in running iis5.0 or iis6.0 in your dev machine.

[Download Azure SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b44c10e8-425c-417f-af10-3d2839a5a362&displaylang=en) and install it before starting the development. It has an Azure emulator to run your app. You will also need to make a config file to test your apps in your dev machine. The SD also has some sample files.

Edit: Sorry. It seems I was wrong [System requirement](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b44c10e8-425c-417f-af10-3d2839a5a362&displaylang=en#Requirements)s for SDK does not include Windows xp and also it requires II7.0