# Azure Service publish on local iis

Tags: iis, wcf, azure, cloud

how can i publish azure service on local iis ??

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668068/windows-azure-cloud-computing-application-with-iis-5-0-or-6-0

Answer (score 2):

Use azure development tools on Visual Studio 2008/10. It provides an enviroment to simulate deploying a service on azure. If you can give more details on what you are trying to, i can give more info.